# aggregate rows and sum frequencies based on name

Tags: r, aggregate

I have this data frame:

| sample | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 1 tattoo | 4 |
| 2 tattoo | 6 |
| 3 tattoo | 3 |
| 4 tattoo | 5 |
| 1 piercing | 2 |
| 2 piercing | 10 |
| 3 piercing | 1 |
| 1 modification | 1 |
| 2 modification | 1 |
| 3 modification | 10 |
| 4 modification | 2 |
| 5 modification | 4 |

```
df <- data.frame(sample = c('1 tattoo', '2 tattoo', '3 tattoo', '4 tattoo',
                            '1 piercing', '2 piercing', '3 piercing',
                            '1 modification', '2 modification', '3 modification', '4 modification', '5 modification'),
                 frequency = c(4, 6, 3, 5,
                               2, 10, 1,
                               1, 1, 10, 2, 4))
```

and I would like to aggregate to know the total frequency of tattooss, piercings and modifications. So that's why when aggregating I need to multiply the frequency by the first number of the row.
This is what I would like to obtain:

| sample | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| tattoo | 45 |
| piercing | 25 |
| modification | 61 |

```
df_expected = data.frame(sample = c('tatto', 'piercing', 'modification'),
                         frequency = c(1*4+2*6+3*3+4*5,
                                       1*2+2*10+3*1,
                                       1*1+2*1+3*10+4*2+5*4))
```

I have tried combining the frequencies one by one, and then I tried to use aggregate, but I am not able to solve it.

```
df$frequency[df$sample == '2 tattoo'] = df$frequency[df$sample == '2 tattoo'] *2
df$frequency[df$sample == '3 tattoo'] = df$frequency[df$sample == '3 tattoo'] *3
df$frequency[df$sample == '4 tattoo'] = df$frequency[df$sample == '4 tattoo'] *4

# same for the rest 

# then use the aggregate  somehow
```

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using combination of `dplyr`, `stringr` and `regex` we can do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
        mutate(sample2 = str_replace_all(sample, "[:digit:]", "") %>% str_squish(),
               sample_num = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", sample)),
               frequency2 = sample_num * frequency) %>%
        group_by(sample = sample2) %>%
        summarise(Frequency = sum(frequency2))
```

Output:

```
  sample       Frequency
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 modification        61
2 piercing            25
3 tattoo              45
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this step by step. E.g. your multipliator is included in the sample name. This can be broken out with `{tidyr}`'s separate function. Then you multiply the frequency and summarise it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
#----------- split your names of form <<id sampletype>> ----------
 separate(sample, into = c("id","sample"), sep = " ") %>%
#------------ multiply --------------------------------------------
 mutate(
   id = as.numeric(id)          # convert id into numeric
 , freq = id * frequency) %>%   # multiply
#------------ group and sum for output ----------------------------
 group_by(sample) %>% 
 summarise(freq = sum(freq))
```

This yields:

```
 # A tibble: 3 x 2
  sample        freq
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 modification    61
2 piercing        25
3 tattoo          45
```

Sample / sort now as wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Base R way :

```
aggregate(num ~ sample, transform(cbind(df[-1], 
            strcapture('(\\d+)\\s(\\w+)', df$sample, 
                       proto = list(num = integer(), sample = character()))), 
          num = num * frequency), sum)

#        sample num
#1 modification  61
#2     piercing  25
#3       tattoo  45
```

- `strcapture` separates `sample` in two columns.
- `transform` multiplies `num` and `frequency`
- `aggregate` summarise the data to calculate `sum` for each `sample`.